# Is there an inverse of `setEditing` for when editing is complete?

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I'm working on a traditional iPhone UINavigationController app, with automatic back buttons etc.

I am working on when an 'edit' button is pressed. The LHS back icon dims, my new one comes in, and then once I tap the 'edit' button again, the back button comes back.

So far, the back button goes away, and my new one comes in, but I can't put it back! I know what the code should be, but I don't know where to call it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
   [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:editing animated:animated];   //fades back button

//de 006 - Load in Move section button here.
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize
                                target:self action:@selector(altersection:)] autorelease];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = saveButton;
```

Basically I want the inverse of `(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {`, where I can do:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;   //custom button hide
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;      //replace back button
```

Is there an inverse of  `(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing`   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I completely understood the question :/

When you press the "Done" button, I believe `setEditing` get's called again, but with `NO` as the ***editing*** parameter.

So in setEditing you could check for:

```
if(editing) { .... }
```

To see if we are entering or leaving the editing state.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pu if condition in setEditing. Same method gets called on any action on edit button.
You can have code like

```
if(self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem)
{
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}
```

You can also check for both conditions in if.